# Not able to retrieve response from Rxjava Retrofit

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

i am trying to get response but i am not getting it. also i am not getting any errors. what i am doing wrong?
made POJO through jsonscema2Pojo.org

may be the way i am calling

```
 @GET("16126940.json")
 Observable <NewsFeed> getFinalData();
```

in soservice is wrong

i am dealing with below json

```
{
  "by": "Doubleguitars",
  "descendants": 70,
  "id": 16126940,
  "kids": [
   16131536,
   16131286,
   16132328,
   16132016,
   16132256,
   16131390,
   16132386,
   16132049,
   16132088,
   16132206,
   16132895,
   16131438,
   16132082,
   16132859,
   16131517,
   16131474,
   16133112
 ],
  "score": 173,
  "time": 1515698746,
  "title": "The Making of Apple’s Emoji",
  "type": "story",
  "url": "https://medium.com/@agzmn/the-making-of-apples-emoji-how-
  designing-these-tiny-icons-changed-my-life-16317250a9ee"
 }
```

my code in activity

```
 public void loadNextDataFromApi(int itemCount) {
    mService = ApiUtils.getSOService2();
}

public void loadAnswers(){
   mService.getFinalData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
  observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<NewsFeed>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() { }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {   }
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(NewsFeed response) {
                        Log.e("response", "response------------------>" + 
                       response.toString());
                    }
                });
}
```

Retrofit Client

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
        return retrofit;
}
}
```

my Service

```
public interface SOService {
    @GET("16126940.json")
    Observable <NewsFeed> getFinalData();
}
```

in Utility i have kept method call

```
 public static final String HTTP_JSON_URL = "https://hackernews.firebaseio.com/v0/item/";
 public static SOService getSOService2() {
    return RetrofitClient.getClient(HTTP_JSON_URL).create(SOService.class); 
}
```

Comment: anyone who can help?

Comment: can you post your model pojo?

Answer (score 0):

May be your error are ignored, As I can see your onError is blank. when you Hit service using RxJava and Retrofit. result will be successful or land in error. so onError should not be blank. put e.printStackTrace() at least. and also make sure  you  have called the method loadAnswers(). your provided code doesn't have that method called..

```
@Override
public void onError(Throwable e) {   
 e.printStackTrace()
}
```

I think you need to call the load answer method in below method.

```
 public void loadNextDataFromApi(int itemCount) {
    mService = ApiUtils.getSOService2();
    loadAnswers();
}
```

Comment: Hello Nitin i am putting debugger compiler is not entering in onError().                 
        mService.getFinalData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
           observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                 .subscribe(new Subscriber<NewsFeed>() the code goes in loop of progress bar

Comment: and i am calling the  loadAnswers(); below ApiUtils.getSOService2();